# OpenCart responsive layout destroy desktop layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, opencart

I am trying to make my opencart responsive. I followed the instructions from here: [How can i make my current opencart theme responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766298/how-can-i-make-my-current-opencart-theme-responsive)

but every time I want to change something in `mobile.css` it affects `desktop.css`. For example I put `#footer{ display:none;}` in `mobile.css` but as a result it kills footer in desktop and tablet.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Does the mobile.css even utilize media queries? Just because it is named mobile.css doesn't mean it is only affecting the mobile view of the site.

Comment: stylebedlinen.com
this is the project I am working on.In every css I put @import url(***.css) only screen and (max-width: ***px);
is it enough or something is missed here?

Comment: work it out in different way now. however could someone post a good tutorial for responsive layouts where I can control size and portrait/landscape modes?

Comment: Does your footer work properly with out mobile.css??Because with wat you mentioned there shouldnt be any problem if you have footer styles in desktop.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile.css will still affect other screen sizes. Wrap your desktop.css with this:

```
@media (min-width: 970px) {

}
```

To display the footer add this to the desktop.css (within the media query above):

```
#footer { display: block; }
```

Based on your comment above it looks like you should change "max-width" to "min-width" in the media query on desktop.css.